# Trouble finding easy way to translate string based on key

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

Basically I have a function that will very simply encrypt a message.

```
def encrypt(message):
    alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    key = ["4","x","z","@","%","b","j","q","(","ƒ","¥","µ","˚","nå","ø","π","å","œ","¢","∞","∫","µ","≈","`","¬","…"]
    new_message = ""
    for x in range(0,len(message)):
        new_message = message.replace(message[x],key.index[alphabet.index(message[x])])
    return new_message

print(encrypt(input("What would you like to encrypt").lower()))
```

This should take the letter and replace it with the character with the same index in list key, however I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: There are better ways of doing this, but your issue is with `key.index[alphabet.index(message[x])]`. Use `key[alphabet.index(message[x])]` instead.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I don't think that's going to work, some of the keys are contained in the alphabet. This is a use-case for `str.translate`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hahah, agreed... didn't see this message until after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally a use case for [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)!

```
def encrypt(message):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    key = '4xz@%bjq(ƒ¥µ˚nåøπåœ¢∞∫µ≈`¬'
    table = str.maketrans(alphabet, key)

    return message.translate(table)

print(encrypt('asdsaewqeq')) # 4œ@œ4%µπ%π
```

Note that one of your entries in `key` is composed of two characters. If this is intentional and you want to replace a single character with two, then you can create your translation table manually.

```
table = dict(zip(map(ord, alphabet), key))
```

Comment: @Sumtinlazy Have you read the `str.translate` docs that are linked?

Comment: Didn't see, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

`key.index()` takes a value and returns its index and it use `()` not `[]` so you need to fix this line:

```
new_message = message.replace(message[x],key.index[alphabet.index(message[x])])
```

to:

```
new_message = message.replace(message[x],key[alphabet.index(message[x])])
```

This will take the letter index and use it to access `key` list and get the value at that index to replace it with the original letter.

**EDIT:**
A better way to do this is to use a `dictionary` and construct a new string isntead, to avoid double `replace()` on the `string`

```
dic = {'a': '4', 'b': 'x', 'c': 'z' ...}
new_message = ''
for x in message:
    new_message += dic[x]
return new_message
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use an intermediate `dict` for creating the mapping of `alphabet` list item  with `key` list item:

```
>>> alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
>>> key = ["4","x","z","@","%","b","j","q","(","ƒ","¥","µ","˚","nå","ø","π","å","œ","¢","∞","∫","µ","≈","`","¬","…"]

# Your `dict` object with the mapping between both the list
>>> encryption_dict = dict(zip(alphabet, key))
```

Then use the above dictionary with the `str.join(...)` to transform your string. For example:

```
>>> my_str = 'stackoverflow'

#  Transform the string using the `dict` and join the chars to form single string           
>>> new_str = ''.join(encryption_dict.get(s, s) for s in my_str)
#                                            ^
#        to return same character if not present in alphabet list

>>> print(new_str)
¢∞4z¥øµ%œbµø≈
```

Comment: This will not work without using an intermediate dummy value because some of the keys are in alphabet.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you meant that some of the characters are *not* present in `alphabet` list? I updated the answer to handle it via using `dict.get(..)`

Comment: This works great, however I'm wondering how exactly this is different than what I was trying before